# didTapAtCoordinate not showing selected Marker - Google Maps IOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift4

I want to change the icon of my selected marker to a deselected one if the user taps on the map.  I am using the following delegate method :

```
 internal func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        print("\(map.selectedMarker) ===> Selected Marker")
    }
```

however `map.selectedMarker` always comes nil. Even when the documentation says `This is called before deselecting any currently selected marker (the implicit action for tapping on the map)`
so I was expecting to be able to see my selected marker.

This is the code I am running when a marker gets  tapped

```
internal func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {

    if map.selectedMarker == marker {
        return true
    }

    if let selectedMarker = map.selectedMarker {
        deselectActiveMarker(currentSelectedMarker: selectedMarker)
    }

    selectMarker(marker: marker)

    return true
}
```

the selectMarker(marker: marker) method is the following one:

```
private func selectMarker(marker: GMSMarker) {

        marker.iconView?.setAnchorPoint(anchorPoint: CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0))

        if let cluster = marker.userData as? GMUCluster {

            let count = "\(cluster.count)" as NSString

            if let icon = UIImage(named: "clusterSelected") {
                marker.iconView = UIImageView(image: createIconWithCount(drawText: count, inImage: icon, isSelected: true))
            }
        }
        else {
            if let icon = UIImage(named: "pinSelected") {
                marker.iconView = UIImageView(image: icon)
            }
        }

        marker.iconView?.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0, y: 0)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 5, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
            marker.iconView?.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
        }, completion: {
            [weak self = self]
            _ in

            guard let instance = self else { return }

            instance.map.selectedMarker = marker
        })
    }
```

Hopefully you can help me. Thanks

Comment: The problem is that you're returning `true` twice in the `didTap` delegate method. You need to clean that method up entirely so that you only return `true` once and at the end of the method. Also, to access the selected marker, you should be accessing it through `mapView` in the method, not `map`.

Comment: about the returns, the first one is placed to stop the execution of the method if you are tapping the same marker. So I think they are ok. About the map... it is an interesting suggestion. I'll give it a try